# Error launching IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, java-6

As I installed two version jdk in my windows, I have defined two system environment variable like this.
[image]

But when I start my IDEA(after computer restarted), it tell me this:

> the environment variable java_home does not point to a valid jvm installation

[image]

When I replace the JAVA_HOME value to the real path,the error disappear.
So, doesn't the environment variable support the placeholder?

Comment: `JAVA_6_HOME` is in C but `JAVA_8_HOME` in F. Are you sure there's no typo? Also make sure if those are overridden in User variables.

Comment: Try http://superuser.com/a/348544/35880

Comment: I indeed put jdk8 in F and 6 in C. And the variable are all system level and they are not overrided in User level.

Comment: Try that link! It mentions a problem with system vs. user variables.

Comment: Hi, David, the link you post is saying "system environment variables may not contain references to user environment variables". Is it the point? But in my case, the variables are all System variables.